# Weird compiler error with "addConstructor" inside template function using LuaBridge

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, luabridge

EDIT: I am using XCode 12.5.1 with GCC. This issue may be limited to GCC because MSC is compiling it without errors. Auggh.

I am trying to set up generic template functions to add classes to LuaBridge. I am getting a weird error on `.addConstructor`. Ultimately I am considering `refl-cpp` to get type names and function info, but for now I am struggling with this issue that has nothing to do with `refl-cpp`.

Here is my template function:

```cpp
struct foo {int bar();};

template<class T, typename ConstructorArgs>
void addclass(lua_State *l)
{
   luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(l)
      .beginNamespace ("bar")
         .beginClass<T>("foo")
            .addConstructor<ConstructorArgs>() // error: Use 'template' keyword to treat 'addConstructor' as a dependent template name
            .addFunction("bar", &foo::bar)
         .endClass()
      .endNamespace();
}

static void my_program()
{
   lua_State *l;
   l = luaL_newstate();
   luaL_openlibs(l);
   addclass<foo, void (*) (void)>(l);
}
```

Note that the `.addFunction` call has no problem. The program compiles and runs correctly if I comment out the `.addConstructor`. The weird part is, if I ignore the `T` template class and hardcode `foo` in the call to `beginClass`, it works:

```cpp
template<class T, typename ConstructorArgs>
void addclass(lua_State *l)
{
   luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(l)
      .beginNamespace ("bar")
         .beginClass<foo>("foo") // hardcoding <foo> here eliminates error and program works
            .addConstructor<ConstructorArgs>()
            .addFunction("bar", &foo::bar)
         .endClass()
      .endNamespace();
}
```

I can't really tell if the problem is in `addConstructor` or `beginClass`.

EDIT: Check out the linked article below. Based on that, the short answer is to change the call to `addConstructor` as follows:

```cpp
.template addConstructor<ConstructorArgs>()
```

This works on both MSC and GCC.

Comment: It would help if you included the "weird compiler error" in your question.

Comment: I included the salient part in the comment in the code. The full error message is "Use 'template' keyword to treat 'addConstructor' as a dependent template name". (I updated the question.)

Comment: Maybe? I'm still working up to speed on C++1y template programming. I did find that page before posting my question, but I'm afraid I couldn't figure how to apply it to my situation (if it applies).

Comment: The hard part was figuring out where to put the "template" keyword. I went ahead and associated this question with the long explanation in the link, but the easy answer was to put the "template" keyword after the period but before the "addConstructor": ".template addConstructor<ConstructorArgs>()"